# Update upper limit /bound of for loop, while in for loop

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to update the upper bound of my for loop, while in the for loop.

Example

```
numvar = 3

for i=2 To numvar Step 2

    'code... 

    numvar = numvar +1

next numvar
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: If I were you I would not do this - updating `For` loop bounds inside the loop is not a good coding practice and can lead to hard-to-track bugs.  If you need a loop which continues while `i` is less than some value then use a `Do...While`

Answer (score 2):

Use a While or Until loop instead:

```
numvar = 3
i = 2
while i <= numvar
   'code ...
   numvar = numvar +1
   i = i + 2
wend
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code sample should have `next i` but it will only loop once because the upper-limit will already have been exceeded.

If you need to change the upper-bound within the loop then I recommend that you use a [Do..Loop](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg264469%28v=office.14%29.aspx) instead; this will be far easier to maintain and control.